# Should matrices be defined in Fortran with more rows than columns? (efficiency)

Tags: arrays, performance, matrix, fortran

Let's imagine that we have an array A of dimensions (i,j). I've read in a number of places that - as Fortran is column-major - loops should be coded as:

```
do j=1,n
  do i=1,n
   ! operate on A(i,j)
  enddo
 enddo
```

At the same time, we should minimize loop overhead, such that, if n>m, then:

```
do j=1,m
 do i=1,n
 ! ...
 enddo
enddo
```

Is more efficient than the other way around. As a consequence of these two statements, if we want to define a matrix with dimensions (2,3) or (3,2), we should go for the second option. Am I right? I have not seen this statement anywhere and I was just wondering if I am missing something. Thank you

Comment: I doubt that an optimization like this matters much.  Fortran 2D arrays are column major.  Do it that way if it makes you feel better, but I'd be surprised if you can measure a significant difference.

Comment: It might once have made a difference but with optimizing compilers being smart enough to rearrange and unroll loops, it may not be important today. Unless you see a bottleneck with a performance analysis tool like gprof, you're better off writing clearer code and leaving optimization to the compiler.

Comment: even following you logic, it only applies to that example where you can arbitrarily  transpose the loop order.  My thinking is if you are frequently operating on whole rows or columns, columns are better because they are contiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a large loop count is better for vectorization because you have a peeling loop and a tail loop, which become negligible when the loop count is large. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_splitting)

But more important : you should but have as a 1st index the dimension where you do stride-1 loops and put the random accesses in the other dimensions. This is much more important than loop count.

Something else which is important is if your 1st index can be a multiple of the vector size. For example, AVX instructions operate on 256-bit vectors which correspond to 4 double precision floats. If your 1st dimension is a multiple of 4 and if your array is 256-bit aligned, all your columns will be aligned and you will be able to get 100% of the vectorization potentiality.
In you example, it could be better to have a matrix declared as (4,2) instead of (3,2) !